# Hibernate : Netbeans genenerates additional POJO class

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans

I got 3 tables :

**Actor** : ID, Name

**Movie** : ID, Title

**Cast** : Movie_ID, Actor_ID

Now I want to JOIN those 3 tables to get actor's list for each movie. It is simple SQL query, but it gets harder with Hibernate.

First of all, I created Cast table like this :

CREATE TABLE Cast (

Movie_id int PRIMARY KEY,

Actor_id int PRIMARY KEY,

FOREIGN KEY (Movie_id) REFERENCES Movie(ID),

FOREIGN KEY (Actor_id) REFERENCES Actor(ID)

)

Then, in Netbeans, I chose New -> Hibernate Mapping Files and POJO's from Database, I added ACTOR, MOVIE and CAST tables and IDE generated 4 instead of 3 classes : Actor.java, Movie.java, Cast.java and **CastId.java**. Class CastId.java seems to be well mapping of Cast table and Cast.java includes only CastId field and getters and setters.

I understand that this is the way Netbeans handles tables which keys have multiple attributes - but why , how does it help me ? Let's say that I want to SELECT * from Cast table which should return list of pairs(Movie_ID, Actor_ID). I can't make it, beacuase when running HQL command

from Cast

it gets only some single ID's - it's beacase Cast has only one field : CastId. On the other hand Netbeans generates CastId but doesn't **CastId.hbm.xml**, so I can't run 'from CastId' either. Am I missing something ? I'm newbie at Hibernate and would like to understand how this should be done.

Comment: You'd better not rely on NetBeans to generate the code for you, and generate it by hand instead. Entities are the core of your app, and their code should be meticulously hand-crafted and documented. You shouldn't have an entity for the CAST table, since it's a pure join table between the other two tables.

Comment: OK so I understand that there is no other way. But how can I skip CAST table ? I've created it because I've had n:m relationship between Actor and Movie, so instead I made Actor-Cast (1:n) and Movie-Cast (1:n). Suppouse I got ACTOR and MOVIE filled with data and that's it. There is no way I could get list of cast for some movie. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I don't know why you came to the conclusion that there is no other way. I specifically said: "You shouldn't have an entity for the CAST table". So, in clear, the code generated by NetBeans is crap. You don't want a list of casts, since a cast has no information at all. What you want is the set of movies an actor has played in, and/or a set of actors playing in a movie. This is a typical ManyToMany association. Take the time to **learn** JPA, by reading a book or tutorial, or even the specifications. Just playing with NetBeans won't lead you anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for advice. But to clarify : I know that my approach (creating CAST table) is good when developing database. Also I've heard from a friend that when working with JPA I should first create entities in database and then generate classes from itusing IDE. I guess you disagree ? Maybe I don't have to create DB at all, just simple classes and then JPA will create entities for me ? I've been to some tutorials and sometimes they did it one way, sometimes the other. What's your opinion ? Thanks for helping.

Comment: Relying on an IDE to generate code that you don't understand, and that you couldn't have generated yourself, is always a bad idea. Generating coe after having designed the tables is perfectly fine, but you have to understand what you're doing. Learn JPA.

Comment: Your assumption that I have no knowledge of JPA at all is wrong. Moreover, I could have genereted code Netbeans had generated myself, I was just looking for most convenient option. Today I've started with Hibernate, I've been learning from many different tutorials and it made me a little bit confused. However your answer sobered me and I finally realized : table CAST is ok and it may be in my database but it's absouletly unnecesary to have such POJO class in my project. Thanks